# Using Lagrange’s Theorem to prove the derivative has a solution in R

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. If $f(D(x))$ is continuous, where $D(x)$ is the Dirichlet function, then there exists a point $c$ such that $f'(c) = 0$

My intuition is that this is true as $f$ is differentiable and continuous. Thus by Lagrange's Theorem there exists a point $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(c) = 0$

However, in that case wouldn’t the statement need to read “$f'(D(c)) = 0$”

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks for the tip. This question is from a sample exam that I found interesting.

Comment: Could you clarify what the Dirichlet function is in this context?  I believe you mean
$$
D(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in \Bbb Q\\
0 & x \notin \Bbb Q.
\end{cases}
$$
Is that correct?

Comment: change the title please.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Argue that $f(D(x))$ can only be continuous if $f(0) = f(1)$.

Comment: Yes that’s what I mean by D(x). I’m not sure how to format like that on this forum

Comment: @S.Miller [Here is a link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360) to formatting instructions for this forum, for future reference.

Comment: Since D(x) oscillates between 0,1 and is nowhere continuous, wouldn’t that in turn make f • D behave similarly and thus not be differentiable?

Comment: @S.Miller I think you mean $f \circ D$ (i.e. $f(D(x))$) instead of $f$.  For "most" functions $f$, it is true that $f \circ D$ oscillates.  If $f(0) = f(1)$, however, then $f(D(x))$ is continuous.

Comment: Then it’s likely false as the way it’s worded seems to imply that it’s true for all functions f

Comment: @S.Miller I don't see how you got that impression. It says "**if** $f(D(x))$ is continuous"